# how to draw grid lines with libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

It's little embarrassing to ask this question. But I can't figure out a way to draw 3 x 3 grid  in the screen with libgdx. Can any of you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html).

Or create meshes for the lines using someMesh.render(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP)

Comment: Oh I see you want to draw lines, as in a tic tac toe? I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I know that but it is what you are asking for. I would not use it but see [this link](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=2910&p=14757&hilit=draw+lines#p14757) mario and nate both respond to a post that recommends using it (nate recommended it, less than a week ago too). Depending on your purpose I would think about the best way to do it, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but any of the three afore mentioned ways _will_ do it.

Comment: For a 3x3 grid I would use a mesh, either by drawing each line individually or by drawing a square and using a texture. Or just use sprites in the same way as the mesh (but I would probably use a mesh)

Comment: ShapeRenderer is actually pretty performant by now. Don't draw a fullblown 3D heightmap with it, but a 3x3 grid for tic tac toe is absolutely no problem.